# Error(10820) and (10822) VHDL

Tags: vhdl

i am trying to write a code but i get error, i dont understand that, i am new to vhdl, any help would be appreciated.

code:

```
entity counter is
    port 
    (
      upp_down : in std_logic;
      rst : in std_logic;
      pressed : in std_logic;
      count : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of counter is

signal count_value: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
   
    process (rst,pressed,upp_down)
    begin
     if(rst'event and rst = '0') then
        count <= "0000";
     else
          if(pressed'event and pressed = '0' ) then
                if(upp_down = '1') then
                  count_value <= count_value + 1;
                elsif(upp_down = '0') then
                  count_value <= count_value - 1;
                end if;
          end if;
     end if;
    end process;
    count <= count_value;
    
end rtl;
```

Errors:

> Error (10820): Netlist error at counter.vhd(28): can't infer register for count_value[1] because its behavior depends on the edges of multiple distinct clocks
>
> Error (10822): HDL error at counter.vhd(28): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge

Comment: To fix it you need to:  remove 'event from reset and reset count_value instead of count.   To beautify the code, change pressed'event ... to falling_edge(pressed) and merge the "else if" and extra "end if" into a single "elsif".

Comment: You can also remove `upp_down` from the sensitivity list.  You're just creating more needless work for the simulator with it present, and it's not affecting the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you're trying to use the edge of two different 'clocks' in one process. A particular process can only respond to one clock.

The second problem is that your code does not translate into any real-world hardware. There's nothing in the FPGA that can respond to there *not* being an edge of a clock, which is what you have described with your `if(rst'event and rst = '0') then` `else` structure.

Nicolas pointed out another problem (which your compiler didn't get as far as), which is that you're assigning `count` both inside and outside a process; this is not allowed, as signals can only be assigned in one process.

Generally the type of reset it looks like you're trying to implement would be written as in the example below:

```
process (rst,pressed,upp_down)
begin
if(rst = '0') then
    count_value <= "0000";
elsif(pressed'event and pressed = '0' ) then
    if(upp_down = '1') then
        count_value <= count_value + 1;
    elsif(upp_down = '0') then
        count_value <= count_value - 1;
    end if;
end if;
end process;

count <= count_value;
```

The reason for changing the reset to affect count_value, is that without this, the effect of your reset would only last one clock cycle, after which the count would resume from where it left off (Thanks @Jim Lewis for this suggestion).

In addition to your compile errors, you should try to use the `rising_edge()` or `falling_edge()` functions for edge detection, as they behave better than the `'event` style.

The reset can be more easily implemented using `count_value <= (others => '0')`; this makes all elements `'0'`, no matter how long `count` is.

Lastly, it looks like you're using the `std_logic_arith` package. There are many other answers discouraging the use of this package. Instead, you should use the `numeric_std` package, and have your counter of type `unsigned`. If your output must be of type `std_logic_vector`, you can convert to this using a cast: `count <= std_logic_vector(count_value);`.

One more thing, I just noticed that your counter is not initialised; this can be done in the same way as I suggested for the reset function, using the `others` syntax.

Comment: I suggest moving count outside of the process and instead reset count_value.

Comment: +1 for Jim's suggestion. Especially since "count" in this version will always be one button-press behind.

Comment: I did think about that, but wasn't sure if there was a reason behind it. Looking at it again this seems unlikely; I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"count" can't be assigned inside and outside a process.

count <= "0000"; <-- inside process

count <= count_value;  <-- outside process.

You should do "count <= count_value;" inside your process :

```
entity counter is


    port 
    (
      upp_down : in std_logic;
      rst : in std_logic;
      pressed : in std_logic;
      count : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)

    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of counter is

signal count_value: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin

    process (rst,pressed,upp_down)
    begin
     if(rst'event and rst = '0') then
        count <= "0000";
     else
          if(pressed'event and pressed = '0' ) then
                if(upp_down = '1') then
                  count_value <= count_value + 1;
                elsif(upp_down = '0') then
                  count_value <= count_value - 1;
                end if;
                count <= count_value;
          end if;
     end if;
    end process;


end rtl;
```